# How would you write a library to be used on android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I've already written a game engine in java using eclipse and opengl es, I had one project (an android project) which contained both of my packages

```
com.logic.engine
com.logic.testapp
```

I wanted a way to keep my engine and test app seperate, I've made an earlier post about how this is done, and I figured out how to reference one project in the build path of another (or just creating a jar file).

My problem is that, lets say I now have my engine all wrapped up in an android project `com.logic.engine`, and now someone would like to use this engine to create a game, so they create an android project `com.someclient.game`, well now because we have one android project referencing another, it crashes everytime.

Now obviously i need the android sdk in my engine package in order to reference things, but its also required on the client app, since the activity is what is actually being run by android.

I guess my question is, how can i create a project for my game engine ***without*** it being an *android* project, but still referencing the android sdk, and without causing it to crash the client app using it?

*edit:*

*note: the client app utilizes the engine flawlessly when its in the same project folder, it isn't until the engine is referenced from another project containing the android sdk that it crashes, so im 99.9% positive it has nothing to do with my code*

Comment: not sure I understand your question. anyway, what happens when you create a regular java project or generic project?

Comment: Crashes how?  Referencing code from another package should not be a problem.

Comment: I thought about this but I wanted to make sure there was a way to create a regular java project, still contain the android sdk (i believe it's just the "android.jar" file? But I wasn't sure if a java project would import windows specific api, in which case i'm not sure the android app would accept it, I could be wrong, but i'm a c programmer, im not too familiar with java

Comment: Mayra, i think it crashes because I have one android project referencing another android project, so i think there is a conflict between the manifest files, but i cannot delete this as it is required in all android projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your game engine project should be an Android library project.  See [Working with library projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject).

Comment: Thank you, very simple solution, this is exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject).

Answer (score 0):

Just a fix for the two links above that no longer work

[Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

[Example Library Tut](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html)